# Poll manager with multiple questions for modx revo

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-snippets

I need a poll manager for modx with the possibility of adding more questions and answers to them. Standard module "Polls" allows add only one question.

I want to use this module for creating system, which can check knowledge of any subject for my students. I need no beautiful viewing of results(like a diagrams etc.), but I want to add questions via admin panel. 
Any ideas?

Comment: And whats wrong about using Categorys to group questions in Polls extra?

Comment: I haven't enough functionality of Polls. It allows set only one question, but I need a pack of questions and giving result for them. It looks like knowledge testing system. not poll "do you like this site?"